# Should we add an encouragement to vote à la MO ?

Tags: feature-request, questions

Just below every MO question appears the following line set off in a box:

> Remember to vote up questions/answers you find interesting or helpful (requires 15 reputation points)

My question: Should we too have something along these lines, to nudge people into voting up questions/answers that they like? I feel that we should: the reminder helps one remember translate one's appreciation into a vote.

I was prompted to ask this question by the rather low proportion of votes scored by even the [most popular questions](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=votes) here. MO questions seem to score around [twice as many votes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions?sort=votes) for the same amount of popularity (~ views).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an interesting idea, but I don't know how to implement it. We have system messages, and we can use one of those, but they are temporary by nature.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/discussion/97/remember-to-upvote-banner/) is some discussion at meta.MO about this.

Comment: I think the link went missing. Also, the MO folks control their software: we don't...

Comment: just added a system message to the main site.

Comment: The message looks encouraging enough :).

Comment: “You can earn a new badge 'Suffrage' if you use all 30 of your allocated votes in a day. Try it !”  This is a nice encouragement.  By the way, I earned the badge just before the message was changed to this (without knowing about the new badge), so yay!

Comment: actually I notice a lot of people who just earned it.